# Find the different point from two different semester for center SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID  Semester  GPA   Center NAme   Date Check in
ID 1  Fall   3.0   A Center -    11/3/2000
ID 1  Fall   3.0   A Center -    11/4/2000
ID 1 Spring  3.5   B Center -    3/3/2000
ID 2 Fall    3.0   B Center -    11/5/2000
ID 3 Fall    3.0   C Center -    11/1/2000
ID 3 spring  3.2   C Center -    3/3/2000
ID 4 Fall    3.2   D Center -    11/10/2000
ID 4 Spring  3.0   D Center -    3/11/2000
.
.
.
```

...

Looking for which Tutoring Center is more effective for students; which center may help students increase their student' GPA.

I would like to get the result like this below.

```
ID  -- Different GPA  -- Center
ID3  --     0.2       --C Center 
ID4  --    -0.4       --D Center 
.
.
.
```

So I know that C Center is more effective compared to D Center.

I found the code for the different GPA between spring and fall semesters for each ID below. However, I could like to group by centers.

```
select DISTINCT(a.[Fake ID]), 
    b.GPA - a.GPA as diff
from tutor a
join tutor b on a.[Fake ID] = b.[Fake ID]
where a.Semester = 'Fall'
and b.Semester = 'Spring'
ORDER BY [Fake ID] DESC;
```

Comment: please edit your question and format your data, is is virtually impossible to read. Also, please describe what the problem is (e.g. current vs expected behavior)

Comment: Diff between _what_?  There are three centers, do you want to compare each possible pair?

Comment: Please let me know if it makes sense now. There are 4 centers (A, B, C, D). I want to see which center is more effective to students, which means whether students' GPA increase more or not for each centers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Center, spring.Gpa - fall.Gpa
FROM tutor t
INNER JOIN tutor fall 
    ON t.ID = fall.ID AND fall.Semester='Fall' AND fall.Center = t.Center
INNER JOIN tutor spring 
    ON t.ID = spring.ID AND spring.Semester='Sprint' AND spring.Center = t.Center
        SELECT t.Id, t.Center, spring.Gpa - fall.Gpa
FROM tutor t
INNER JOIN tutor fall 
    ON t.ID = fall.ID AND fall.Semester='Fall' AND fall.Center = t.Center
INNER JOIN tutor spring 
    ON t.ID = spring.ID AND spring.Semester='Sprint' AND spring.Center = t.Center
```